# AJAX don't trigger WebMethod but returns whole HTML page on success

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod, scriptmanager

I am having trouble making a WebMethod to work. It's all set up properly, and i have simplified it to the smallest example.

**AJAX**:

```
function DoAJAX() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'faq.aspx/DoAJAX',
    data: "AJAX Test",
    dataType: 'text', 
    success: function (data, status) {
        debugger;
        alert(status + " " + data)
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error!")
    }
 });
}
```

**WebMethod** (in *faq.aspx.cs*, using *System.Web.Services*; and *public static*):

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string DoAJAX(string foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

**HTML** (*faq.aspx*, with *ScriptManager* and *EnablePageMethods*)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MP.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="faq.aspx.cs" Inherits="Lottery.faq" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <input type="button" value="AJAX" onclick="DoAJAX()" />
</asp:Content>
```

When clicked, the AJAX call returns a **success** with the following contents in *data*: http://pastebin.com/X0Vke0qj

A breakpoint in **DoAJAX()** *WebMethod* is never reached.

Why don't it return the "*AJAX Test*" string that was sent, why the *WebMethod* isn't hit?

Comment: I just tried it, and i get the same reply (data = whole HTML document). And the breakpoint in WebMethod isn't triggered.

Comment: In your `web.config` do you also have `ScriptModule` registered under `httpModules`? If that's missing it won't work either.

Comment: Scott: i don't have ScriptModule in web.config (is pretty much empty), can you explain in more detail what to add please? Also your previous suggestion didn't work. ("error!")

Comment: guys, this worked for me using json but I also changed other stuff.

Comment: When i add it inside <sytem.web> i get 500.22 error "An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode." The whole web.config: http://pastebin.com/tDM3AKSe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change type to json, add content type and in data, pass foo parameter as json.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'faq.aspx/DoAJAX',
    data: "{ 'foo': 'AJAX Test' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status + " " + data.d)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("error!")
    }
});
```

Comment: I copied your whole AJAX and replaced mine, then run it. I get "error!" alert.

Comment: it may be because you did other changes in your application like these edits in your web.config. Please undo all changes. If you still get an error check xhr, status and error variables I've added and tell what error you get.

Comment: With your answer: xhr: http://pastebin.com/7kFLWbCd - error: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: did you undo your changes to the original code? is the web method exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, everything is exactly like in the original question. It had something different. I guess is working, please wait for my feedback.

Comment: Your error message suggest me that you changed the name of the parameter in the web method and because of that is crashing. You called the parameter "values" instead of "foo".

Comment: Yes, you are right on that and in the rest of the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnCallAjax").click(function () {
                DoAJAX();
            });

            function DoAJAX() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "faq.aspx/DoAJAX",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{foo:"AJAX Test"}',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        debugger;
                        alert(status + " " + data.d)
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error!")
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnCallAjax" value="Call AJAX" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class faq : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string DoAJAX(string foo)
    {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your whole function and run it. I get "error!" alert.

Comment: Copy and paste the code exactly the way I have it.Don't add any extra logic or controls and it will work.It's working perfectly fine on my side